# Horizontal scrolling needed to view site on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I have a website based Wordpress and for some strange reason when I open it through my iPhone or any other mobile device I only see the background of the site and only if I scroll a lot to the right I can see the full site.

I attached a screenshot so you can all see what I mean or just try opening http://sivantalmor.com and see by yourself.

Is there CSS I can use to fix this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what's causing this, but this seems to work:

Add the `overflow-x: hidden;` property to your div#main

**Like so:**

```
<div id="main" role="main" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
</div>
```

Edit:

The problem is here:

```
<div class="audio-player" style="direction: ltr;"></div>
```

You could remove `direction: ltr;` that's the one causing all this. But then you'll have to fix some margins for the element wrapping the album photo.

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem is in the audioplayer part (#soundcheck_audio_player_widget-2).
Inside is the link .jp-pause, which is positioned wide outside the div to the left.
This causes the page to generate a long scrollbar to the left.
You can add overflow: hidden; to this Class: .jp-controls-wrap

```
.jp-controls-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It does the trick!

Comment: Thank you! I already added the code from the earlier reply and it works well as well... I suppose it does the same effect. doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, in general, both hide the element outside the wrapper and prevent the overflow.
If you have to position something outside the wrapper, you would run into problems with the solution of estrar though.

The difference is that my solution only hides what really has to be hidden, to prevent the scrollbar, you may can call it cleaner maybe.